# Laravel: Refresh Jquery datatable without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, datatable

I'm using laravel Eloquent to fetch data from table. My code like below.

Controller

```
public function index(){
    $plants = Plant::all();

    return view('views.plant',compact('plants'));
}
```

View (table)

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead>
    <tr class="table-success">
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Plant</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th class="text-center">Edit</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="myTable">     
<?php $count =1; ?>

@foreach($plants as $plant)
    <tr>
        <input  value="{{$plant->id}}" type="hidden"/>                                            
        <td>{{$count}}</td>
        <td>{{$plant->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$plant->plant_code}}</td>
        <td>{{$plant->place}}</td> 
        <td class="text-center"><a  class="edit-btn modal-trigger" data-target="modal-plant-edit"><i class="material-icons black-text">edit</i></a></td>                                  
    </tr>
    <?php $count++ ?>                                    
@endforeach
```

I need to refresh my table with button click without reloading my page. I tried `$('#datatable').dataTable().ajax.reload();`, `$("#datatable").dataTable().fnDestroy();`, `$('#datatable').dataTable().fnDraw();` methods with my button click but it's not working. How can i fix this?

Comment: Have you set up your Datatable to use [Ajax](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax)?

Comment: @kerbholz No, I didn't do that. I'm little bit confuse to do that in laravel.

Comment: You'd set up a route (i.e. `/api/plants`) that returns a JSON response of your plants (`Plant::all()`). [Setup your Datatable](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) and your route as url `url: '/api/plants'`. (btw, I assume you are using https://datatables.net)